# I cannot complete the registration process in my project that I developed with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In the system I developed with pdo, the membership process gives a successful response, but it does not save it to the database.

```
    <?php
@session_start();

if($_POST['posta'] and $_POST['sifre']){ 

 $uye_kulad = $_POST['adi'];
 $uye_kulsoyad = $_POST['soyadi']; 
 $uye_kultel = $_POST['tel'];
 $uye_kuladres = $_POST['AdresMetni']; 
 $uye_mail = $_POST['posta']; 
 $uye_sifre = md5($_POST['sifre']); 
 $uye_sifre2 = md5($_POST['sifre2']); 

 if(empty($uye_kulad) or empty($uye_mail) or empty($uye_sifre) or empty($uye_sifre2)){ 
   echo "Lütfen bütün alanları doldurun."; 
} 
else{ 
 $kontrol = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM uyelik_islem WHERE uye_posta=?"); 
 $kontrol->execute(array($uye_mail)); 
 if($kontrol->rowCount()){  
   echo "Kayıt Olmaya Çalıştığınız E-Posta Sistemde Kayıtlı !"; 
}  
else if(strlen($uye_kulad) < 5 and strlen($uye_sifre) < 6){ 

   echo "Kullanıcı adı 5, şifre 6 karakterden az olamaz!"; 
   } 
   else if ($uye_sifre != $uye_sifre2){ 
   echo "Şifreler eşleşmiyor!"; 
   }  
   else { 
   $ekle = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO uyelik_islem      (uye_adi,uye_soyadi,uye_posta,sifre,uye_tel,uye_adres,dtarih) 
    VALUES('$uye_kulad','$uye_kulsoyad','$uye_mail','$uye_sifre','uye_kultel','uye_kuladres',now()   )"); 

     if($ekle) { 
     echo "<script>alert('Üye kaydedildi');
     location.href='giris_yap.php'</script>"; 
    }else { 
     header("Kayıt işlemi başarısız! Lütfen site yönetimi ile iletişim kurun."); 
    } 
  } 
 } 
} 

?>
```

I changed the order of operations, tried the switch case and the result is still the same

Comment: From PHP's [md5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) manual: "_Warning It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See the [Password Hashing FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) for details and best practices._"

Comment: Where is `$pdo` set?

Comment: What is your `header()` call supposed to do?

Comment: **Warning:** Some of your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use prepared statements **and parameters**, in _all cases_ to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: `$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO` ...is not followed by an `execute()` command, so of course it will never send anything to the database.